# Order of emails is changed when sending multiple emails with CFMail

Tags: coldfusion

I have an issue while sending the below two emails through CF 2016. When I run my code I'm receiving the "Password" email first and then the "Username" mail second. The order of sending is getting changed. I need to get "Username" mail first and then "Password" mail. How can I resolve this?

```
<cfmail to="#toEmail#" from="#fromEmail#" subject="Username" type="html">
      Your username is #username#
</cfmail>

 <cfmail to="#toEmail#" from="#fromEmail#" subject="Password" type="html">
      Your password is #password#
 </cfmail>
```

Comment: How is mail set up on your server?  Are you using a spool?

Comment: Why on earth would you print a password in plaintext and send it in a message?

Comment: You can't control which email gets sent in which order once it leaves the CF server. That's controlled by the mail server.

Comment: You are likely dumping your emails into a queue that is getting read top to bottom, so the last message in (password) is being sent first. Check your mail server config. Also, to echo TRose, sending a password through email is a very bad practice. Is this a temporary password you are setting for them? If it's a password they entered, this is even worse. A password should never be readable, recoverable or reversible.

Comment: Also, if it's a temporary password, it should be _VERY_ temporary.

Comment: "You can't control which email gets sent in which order once it leaves the CF server"  .... Adding to what AdrianJ.Moreno said, even disabling spooling won't change that.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, it is temporary password

Comment: @Dan Bracuk I'm using **relay.appriver.com** as my mail server. The checkbox for **Spool mail messages for delivery** is checked in my CF admin settings

Comment: Is that the problem? What is spooling actually do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooling#Uses_and_advantages

Comment: Turning off mail spooling in CF Admin can cause your page to not complete loading until the mail is sent. That may not be what you want. As far as the sending order, I don't believe CF spool uses first in - first out. I think it just batches mail in the spool or possibly uses last in - first out. I'm not sure. What happens if you switch the order of your cfmail tags?

Comment: @AbhilashShajan  - Ultimately delivery is out of your hands once the email leaves the CF server. So even if you could modify the order CF processes them, there's still no guarantee they'll arrive in a user's inbox in that same order.

Comment: @Shawn Oh, you are saying it is in LIFO order. Let me check.

Comment: @Shawn Switching the order of cfmail tags is not working :-(

Comment: IIRC with ColdFusion 7 (and possibly 8 as well), spooled emails went out in the order in which they were spooled (FIFO). That went out the window with CF 9+. If you really want to change the order in which the emails are received by the user, then you can track opens (using a 1x1 pixel) on the "username" email, and when the email is opened, then (and only then) send the "password" email. Of course this only works if the user enables images in the email....

Answer (score 2):

You can disable mail spooling on a per `cfmail` basis with `spoolEnable`. It does slow down the page though. Try it on only the first email. That will send out the first email immediately. Then let the second email get spooled for idle/later delivery.

```
<cfmail to="#toEmail#" from="#fromEmail#" subject="Username" type="html" spoolEnable="no">
      Your username is #username#
</cfmail>
<cfmail to="#toEmail#" from="#fromEmail#" subject="Username" type="html">
      Your username is #username#
</cfmail>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always to do something like this:

```
<cfmail to="#toEmail#" from="#fromEmail#" subject="Username" type="html">
      Your username is #username#
</cfmail>

<cfthread name="SendPassword" action="run">
<cfscript>
sleep(appropriate number of milliseconds);
</cfscript>
 <cfmail to="#toEmail#" from="#fromEmail#" subject="Password" type="html">
      Your password is #password#
 </cfmail>
</cfthread>
```

Look at your spool settings to get the appropriate number of milliseconds.